# mongod as custom linux service

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB using tar file in RHEL 6.5. I am able to start mongod as standalone but would like to register it as a service.

I think installing using yum does that, but I would like to use the tar file installation method only.

Is there any script I should edit to add mongod as a service so that I can run it as a service instead of keeping the terminal opened?

Comment: Why not use the rpm installer, which does exactly what you want?

Comment: Just curious if there is other way of registering it as a service like we do for Windows.

Comment: You said you were using RHEL 6.5. Yes, you can replicate the steps that the rpm install will do. But you have not really explained why you don't want to just use the rpm install?

Comment: I don't want auto-updates. But seems we can turn this off somehow in yum. May be I just should use the RPM installer. thank you!